# Cherrypy - reciving JSON data 404, 'Missing parameters'

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, cherrypy

I'm making my own site from scratch using Cherrypy Postgresql. I am a [beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675723/fix-a-404-missing-parameters-error-from-a-get-request-to-cherrypy) with Python and Javascript but I am very enthusiastic about learning those two programming languages.

---

What I am trying to achieve right now is to `fill up HTML form` -> `Send data using` [JSON](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html?highlight=json#dealing-with-json) `by AJAX` -> `Define Rights for a visitor` -> and `redirect to index` after its all done.

---

I am fighting with this error for days because I cannot find an example on the internet how to send data in python by AJAX using JSON

---

As I said I am a beginner so point all bad behaviours in code I am making, please :)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpdispatch.py", line 60, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dataString'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 670, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\encoding.py", line 221, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpdispatch.py", line 66, in __call__
    raise sys.exc_info()[1]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpdispatch.py", line 64, in __call__
    test_callable_spec(self.callable, self.args, self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpdispatch.py", line 163, in test_callable_spec
    raise cherrypy.HTTPError(404, message=message)
cherrypy._cperror.HTTPError: (404, 'Missing parameters: dataString')
```

---

### **Cherrypy engine printout**

```
[12/Jun/2017:13:44:03]  Testing database is disabled, deleting test users... skipping...
[12/Jun/2017:13:44:03]  ====== INIT SQL ======
[12/Jun/2017:13:44:03]  Connecting to PostgreSQL database...
[12/Jun/2017:13:44:03]  Testing engine is enabled, adding record...
[12/Jun/2017:13:44:03]  ====== INIT SRV ======
[12/Jun/2017:13:44:03] ENGINE Bus STARTING
CherryPy Checker:
The Application mounted at '' has an empty config.

[12/Jun/2017:13:44:03] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[12/Jun/2017:13:44:03] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\servers.py:411: UserWarning: Unable to verify that the server is bound on 8080
  warnings.warn(msg)
[12/Jun/2017:13:44:08] ENGINE Serving on http://0.0.0.0:8080
[12/Jun/2017:13:44:08] ENGINE Bus STARTED
```

---

### Python Login method

```
class Root(object):
    exposed = True

    @cherrypy.expose
    # @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    @cherrypy.tools.accept(media='application/json')
    def login(self, dataString):
        # cherrypy.request.method == "POST":
        self.addHeader()
        db = config()
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**db)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        is_logged_in = None
        bad_username = None
        bad_password = None
        json.load(dataString)
        # input_json = cherrypy.request.json()
        # dataString = input_json["dataString"]
        # - Login
        username_input = dataString[0]
        if username_input == cur.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = %s;", (username_input)):
            username_password = dataString[1]
            if username_password == cur.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE password = %s;", (username_password)):
                return is_logged_in
            else:
                return bad_password
        else:
            return bad_username

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        self.addHeader()
        return "ok"
```

---

### Javascript .js override submit function

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
    var dataString = [];
    dataString.login = $("#login").val();
    dataString.password = $("#password").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/login',
      data: JSON.stringify(dataString),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
      },
      error: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
      }
    });
});
```

---

### HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
      <form action="/process_form/" method="post">
      <!-- id="myForm" class="login-form"> -->
        <input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="login"/>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password"/>
        <button form="myForm" type="submit">Login</button>
        <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AJAX data you'll receive in in your `login` function is not contained in the parameter `dataString` (actually, you will not get any parameter) but in `cherrypy.request.json`.

Thus you should change your login function as follows:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
def login(self):
    json_obj = cherrypy.request.json
    ...
```

Note that you will receive an actual object (dict / list) based on the AJAX parameters, not a string.

Another note: `cherrypy.request.json` is only filled if you've set the decorator `@cherrypy.tools.json_in()` (as you already did).